'no operator "=" matches these operands' in C++
I am attempting to make a board object for a tic tac toe game, and can't get around this error.
class Board {
    public:
        void reset() {
            board[3][3] = {
                {" ", " ", " "},
                {" ", " ", " "},
                {" ", " ", " "}
            };
        };

    private:
        std::string board[3][3];

    Board() {
        reset();
    };
        
};

I've tried switching the variable type from std::string to char but it throws a different error which makes no sense either

If the type of the expression board is string[3][3], what is the type of board[3][3]?

You cannot assign arrays in C++. And please don't spam tags, C and C++ are very different languages.

Unrelated: std::string is not a good choice to store a single character.

board[3][3] is a single string, and it is also out of bounds for the array. Valid indices are 0, 1, and 2.

Why is the constructor private?

Side note:  If you append an extra column, you could place a '\n' in the last column.  For the last cell, use '\0' (NULL).  This allows you to print the board with a single statement like std::cout << board << "\n";  One extra column allows you to treat the board as a C-Style string.

I think you may have an issue with your reset() method of the Board class. It's trying to change the value of the board member variable (of type String[][]) using the = operator which is not possible because arrays are not assignable in C++.
There are two fixes that I see for this issue:
the fix I would use (if you want to keep the same vibe of your code) is to loop over every value in the board and set the strings individually to " " like this:
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        board[i][j] = " ";
    }
}

changing the class to look like this:
class Board {
public:
    void reset() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                board[i][j] = " ";
            }
        }
    };

private:
    std::string board[3][3];

    Board() {
        reset();
    };
};

However, if you are looking for something more modern, I'd recommend the C++ std::array instead of a raw array. Utilizing the std::array would give you access to the built-in fill() method (i.e. std::array::fill) to initialize the array as follows:
<< corrected >>
#include <array>
#include <string>

class Board {
public:
    void reset() {
        board.fill(std::array<std::string, 3>{" ", " ", " "});
    };

private:
    std::array<std::array<std::string, 3>, 3> board;

    Board() {
        reset();
    };
};


Thank you so much, just beginning learning C++ and this is very useful

Thank you @TedLyngmo, you are 100% correct! I completely forgot that it's a 2d array, and never tried it in my IDE. I've updated my answer accordingly.
